# Tkinter GUI: Adding new entry boxes using .grid() when button is pressed

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, layout, tkinter

I'm trying to create new entry boxes when the "ADD entry" is used for my program. I do realize that the 'pack codes' works when I run it individually, but when I combine with existing program which is in `grid()`, the window is not showing when I run my program.

I also understand that we should not to use both `.pack()` when I have other things using `.grid()` in the same program. Hence, my question is, how do I create new entry boxes in grid.

I have tried finding elsewhere but they all suggested pack. For instance: I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833655/creating-new-entry-boxes-with-button-tkinter) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211524/using-entry-box-with-tkinter-in-grid-manager), etc etc, to name a few; but couldn't find anything similar to mine. I would like to add entry boxes below the current entry boxes which is at row 3.

I'm kind of new to Python; (am using Python 2.7 and tkinter module in this program. Thank you very much for the help!
My simplified error codes are as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter
import os

class Window:

 def __init__(self, master):

    self.filename3=""
    csvfile=Label(root, text="NUMBERS").grid(row=3, column=0)
    bar=Entry(master).grid(row=3, column=3)
    self.entryText3 = StringVar()
    self.bar = Entry(root, textvariable=self.entryText3).grid(row=3, column=3)

    #BUTTONS
    self.cbutton= Button(root, text="OK", command=self.process_csv)
    self.cbutton.grid(row=15, column=6, sticky = W + E)

####PROBLEM FROM HERE#####
    all_entries = []
    addboxButton = Button(root, text='ADD', fg="BLUE", command=self.addBox)
    addboxButton.pack()

#I have also tried replacing the last 2 lines with the following 2 lines instead but to no avail:     
#self.addboxButton = Button(root, text='ADD THA-ID', fg="BLUE", command=self.addBox)
#self.addboxButton.grid(row=3, column=6)

    frame_for_boxes = Frame(root)
    frame_for_boxes.pack()

 def addBox(self):
    print "ADD"
    next_row = len(all_entries)
    lab = Label(frame_for_boxes, text=str(next_row+1))
    lab.grid(row=next_row, column=0)
    ent = Entry(frame_for_boxes)
    ent.grid(row=next_row, column=0)
    all_entries.append( ent )

 def process_csv(self):
    #own program here
    print "program"
root = Tk()
window=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I also understand that we should not to use both .pack() when I have other things using .grid() in the same program."_ - that is not a correct statement. You can use both `grid` and `pack` in the same _program_, just not for two or more widgets that share the same _parent_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your program other than the one you stated:

1. Inside the initializer (`__init__()`) you attached the widgets to `root` which is not defined within the scope of your `Window` class. The reasonable way to fix this issue is when you use an instance of [`Tk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#Tkinter.Tk), id est `root` id est `master` in `Window`  class, make it as an *instance variable*. This means the first thing you have to do in the inititializer is this : `self.master = master`. This will **result** in you having to replace all `root` occurrences within `__init__()` by `self.master`
2. The second issue to fix is the one you specified in your question's title: you can not mix the `grid()` and `pack()` layout managers for the same widget container. You have to decide which one. Since you placed most of the widgets using `grid()`, I suggest you to get rid of `pack()`. This means:

   - `addboxButton.pack()` becomes, for example, `addboxButton.grid(row=0, column=1)`
   - `frame_for_boxes.pack()` becomes, for example, `frame_for_boxes.grid(row=0, column=0)`
3. The previous list item fixes the problem but it will make you discover other issues within your program which are related:

   - `NameError: global name 'all_entries' is not defined`
   - `NameError: global name 'frame_for_boxes' is not defined`

   This is because those widget variables are not reachable within the scope of `addBox()` function. To resolve this issue, you have to make those 2 elements as *instance variables*. This means:

   - `all_entries = []` becomes `self.all_entries = []`
   - `frame_for_boxes = Frame(root)` becomes `self.frame_for_boxes = Frame(self.master)` (remember we replaced `root` by `self.master` in **1.**)

   The **consequence** of this error fixing is that you have to use all over inside your program:

   - `self.all_entries` instead `all_entries`
   - `self.frame_for_boxes` instead of `frame_for_boxes`
4. For scalability reasons, I think you will have at least to make the rest of widgets as instance variables (i.d. prefix them with the `self` keyword)
5. As your real project is more complicated than what you show in this MCVE, I encourage you to adopt the [SaYa idiom](https://www.begueradj.com/tkinter-saya-idiom.html) when creating and placing widget elements. This means you will need to replace:

   ```
     csvfile=Label(root, text="NUMBERS").grid(row=3, column=0)
   ```

   by

   ```
     self.csvfile = Label(self.master, text="NUMBERS")
     self.csvfile.grid(row=3, column=0)
   ```

   To avoid unexpected bugs in your program, you must do the same for the remaining widgets you declared in the inititialzer.
6. There are also other things I would like to mention, but most of them are available on [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do it to create a command which creates the entries and stores the new entries inside of a variable.
In my case, I use Entry_i and store in Entries but you can use self.Entries to make communication easier. (python 3.5)

```
def Make_Entry(self, root, Entries, x, y):

    Entry_i = Entry(root, bd = 5)
    Entry_i.grid(row = x, column = y, sticky = W+E+N+S)
    Entries.append(Entry_i)
    return(Entries, x+1, y+1)
```